# Wordpress Admin: open popup window on a custom button

Tags: wordpress

I am using custom meta box in wordpress post page. this box contains a custom Copy button. Now, I want to open a popup window on clicking 'copy' button. Also I need to show content of parent window in this popup. I have attached the screenshot of metabox ![enter image description here][1]for reference.

Comment: This should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I moved it to wordpress.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onclick to do that.

For exemple you may try this

```
onClick="window.open('http://youradresspage/');"
```

Your_pop_up_page must be in your theme folder and of course you can call everything in this page, like the content from parent page.